# Blend Filter Not apply when call canvas function `loadFromJson`

Tags: filter, fabricjs, blending

When I perform `blend` filter on the image and convert canvas into JSON

Then It again I load canvas from that JSON, at that time my filter not applied.

I am using a fabric version 1.7.22

My filter code is like below :

```
canvas.getActiveObject().filters.push(new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
                    color: '#ff0000',
                    mode: 'add',
                    alpha: 0.8
                }))
canvas.getActiveObject().applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

All other filter is working perfectly after the canvas load into JSON but only blend filter not work.
Is there any property missing in my filter?

I have created one fiddle that represents the issue : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/1pc95xef/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug caused by `Blend.toObject()` not saving its class type, so `Blend` filter ends up without `type: 'Blend'` when serialized. To deserialize the object correctly, Fabric parses its `type` property, and when it doesn't find one for the serialized filter, it just abandons it.

Here's a patch you can use to fix this:

```
fabric.Image.filters.Blend.prototype.toObject = function() {
  return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {
    color: this.color,
    image: this.image,
    mode: this.mode,
    alpha: this.alpha
  });
}
```

`BaseFilter.prototype.toObject()` does set the `type` property, so it makes sense to just extend `Blend.prototype.toObject()` from the object it returns.

P.S: the latest fabric.js 2.4+ doesn't have this issue so it's one more reason to upgrade.

Comment: @mayurkukadiya Sure, here's a fork of your fiddle with the patch: http://jsfiddle.net/kcn2Lv9e/ . Just make sure it gets called *before* serializing the filters.